# Object instancing for 3D tileset

Tags: instances

I've been using Blender to create a 3D tileset for a game.

In my scene I have an object for each tile that I have built.

When I want to test my tileset I make copies of the tile objects and place them accordingly in another part of the scene.

It would be great if instead of making copies I could define these objects instead as instances of the original tile objects, such that when I update an original tile, all instance update too.

How can this be achieved in Blender?

Comment: Copy them using Alt+D keys.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I needed, thank you.  As I understand this is essentially creating a new object that references the same mesh as the original.